# Custom color and alpha in tab bar

Tags: ios, xcode

i'm trying to change the color of a tabbar in my app, i use this line of code to change the color of it:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

I want to add a translucent iOS 7 effect but with a green color. I've changed translucent property but i don't see any result.

Answer (score 1):

Change `UITabBarController`'s alpha:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;

    [tabBarController.tabBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [tabBarController.tabBar setAlpha:0.2];

}
```

or with `appearance` in the same `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setAlpha:0.2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the color on the storyboard by selecting the root: Tab Bar View Controller, select the tab bar, and adjust the Background (or tint) color in the attributes inspector, or you can adjust the code with the barTintColor:

```html
// Adjust the Color of the Tab Bar itself
self.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

// Adjust the Color of the selected Icon in the Tab Bar
self.tabBar.tintColor = [Single single].singleThemeColorTint;
```

If you need to adjust the ALPHA too, I would use:

```html
UIColor *charcoal = [UIColor colorWithRed:66/255.0
                                            green:79/255.0
                                             blue:91/255.0
                                            alpha:1];
   // For Tab Bar
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = charcoal;

 // For selected Item Highlight
    self.tabBar.tintColor = charcoal;
```

I created a View Controller File for the Tab Bar Story Board, and ran this code in ViewDidLoad{ }